# IsAssignableFrom misses interface inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, interface

Doing something like this

```
...
if (!settingsType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (ISettingsSource)))
            throw new IncorrectCustomizationSourceTypeException(settingsType.Name, nameof(ISettingsSource));
...
```

and actually i got my lovely exception in spite of `settingsType is instance of class which derived from a class that implements required interface`. 
As I've understood that method check casting ability to type passed in parameter and in my case it should work.

What is the proper way to check such condition than?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You read it like To instead of From.

Answer (score 4):

[IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) has a counter-intuitive form (i.e. reversed) from what a person might think in the first place. Your condition should be:

```
if (!typeof(ISettingsSource).IsAssignableFrom(settingsType))
```

according to this paragraph from the documentation:

> Return Value Type: 
>   System.Boolean 
>   **true** if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> ...
>
> The current instance is an interface that c implements.

Comment: +1 though I don't think it's that counter intuitive. E.g. `object` is assignable from `string`, so `typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))` is `true`, and so on.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, but I think most humans will expect a form that goes like: "this type is deriving from", not something like "the base for this type is ".  Most of us think of `settingsType` as the subject, and the subject [usually comes first](https://www.englishrules.com/writing/2005/subjects-and-verbs-and-sentence-order/).

Comment: It's a prepositional statement, subject and object order depends on the preposition.